# ASP.NET MVC Razor Check DB Entry

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to add Video and Image on my site.   When entry added in DB I want to check if user added picture and only  then display it.

I think structure must be like this

```
if(rows.count > 0)
{ 
    <img src = ="Uploads/@item.Image" />
}
else <img src ="" />
```

I hope  you understand what I  want please Help Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure which part you need help. If you want to display/hide image based on a DB flag, set a property on your viewModel object and check its value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your having a problem taking the content of the image from the database and putting it into the HTML: you cannot just do that. Remember `img` tags do not just contain the binary data of an image rather they have a URL from which the browser will fetch the image. So you need another action (and probably controller) for images which outputs (with the right HTTP content type) the binary image. The image tag in your HTML contains the [URL for this new action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Ie. you need *two* actions. One for the HTML and one for the image content.

So in your razor view:

```
if(rows.count > 0) { 
  <img src = ="@Url.Action("get", "image", new { id = @item.id })" alt="…" />
}
```

And then in the `Get` action of the `ImageController` you set [`Response.ContentType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contenttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to match the image type, and stream the image out (a [`ContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) makes this easire).

**NB** putting access to the database in your view is poor practice: you should be populating a model type from the database in your controller, or better, having your controller orchestrate the model to populate itself (and possibly an instance of a view model type) and then pass that instance (having closed the database connection) to the view.

**PS.** If the image is small, you could look an inlining a data URL, but this is not suitable for images of more than a few kB in size.

Comment: I'm saving  in db only path of Image  on my server, will try thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  @if (!Model.Image.IsEmpty())
                        {
                            <figure><img src="~/Uploads/@Model.Image" alt=""></figure>

                        }
```

tried this and works.